# Register single click on list item child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<li class="is_tab" id="geometry_tab">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#geometry_tab_collapse">
         <i class="pe-7s-plugin"></i>
         <p>Geometry
            <b class="caret"></b>
         </p>
     </a>
     <div class="collapse" id="geometry_tab_collapse">
         <ul class="nav">
             <li class="is_tab" id="pipe_geometry_tab"><a href="#">Pipe Geometry</a></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
</li>
```

Using jQuery, my objective is to retrieve the `<li>` id on click, irrespective of whether the user clicks `li.is_tab`, `li.is_tab > a`, `li.is_tab > a > p`, or `li.is_tab > a > i`. Moreover, I would like the same event handler to be capable of distinguishing between clicks on `#pipe_geometry_tab` and `#geometry_tab`, i.e., simply returning a single, correct id when one or the other is clicked.

## My question is this:

Given the following snippet,

```
$(<selector>).on("click", function(){...})
```

is there a `<selector>` that will register a *single* click on `li.is_tab` regardless of whether it or its `a`, `i`, or `p` children is clicked?

If not, I would appreciate any recommendations on how to go about this.

PS I've tried quite a few things, but rather than bloat this post with them, I'm hoping someone more experienced feels this has an obvious solution.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: It's often better to use the index of the tab rather than an ID, or some other abstract property. It's best to not tightly couple your function to DOM characteristics that can change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li.is_tab').on("click", function(e){...});
```

^^ that should work fine and anything that is clicked on the `li` will be handled.

If you want the `li` that was clicked you can look at `e.currentTarget` if you want to see the actual element that was clicked you can use `e.target`

---

So if you want the `id` of the `li` that was clicked you can use `e.currentTarget.id`

Comment: Aha! I was using `target`, not `currentTarget` when I attempted this solution in a sleepy haze last night. Excellent. However, when logging the id to console, clicking on `#pipe_geometry_tab` prints both geometry_tab and pipe_geometry_tab.

Comment: @MackieMesser May want to add `e.stopPropagation()` to the top of your event function otherwise the event gets bubbled up to another li higher up in the chain.

Comment: Although I think that suggestion would probably fix the issue, it also seems to disable the `collapse` functionality of `<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#geometry_tab_collapse">`. Can I have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: ha because it is stopping propagation,  so those events will not bubble up. You _may_ need to rely on some trickery.

Comment: Although  that would be out of scope for this question @MackieMesser . Maybe mark an answer here as accepted and then create a follow up? :-)